# Understanding the bloom filter

Tags: c

I was taking a look at the following example:
https://www.timdoug.com/etc/bloom_filter.c

to try and understand the bloom filter

I get to this portion of code which I cannot understnad :

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_HASHES; i++) {
        /* xor-fold the hash into FILTER_SIZE bits */
        hash[i] = (hash[i] >> FILTER_SIZE) ^ 
                  (hash[i] & FILTER_BITMASK);
        /* set the bit in the filter */
        filter[hash[i] >> 3] |= 1 << (hash[i] & 7);
    }
```

what exactly is happening here and why is this being performed( I understand the operators but I'm not getting why they are being used here)

Comment: Which part specifically don't you understand? There's three different lines here (including the loop itself).

Comment: I udnerstand that the loop runs on each of the hashing functions' array. I don't understand what it does exactly to that array

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter#Algorithm_description

Comment: I still don't understand how the position of hashed string is determined. in case of the int array hash[ARRAY_SIZE], how do I determine where the hashed string goes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this part of the algorithm looks buggy (at least for the case that FILTER_SIZE is meant to be chosen freely): Assume that `FILTER_SIZE` is 10 (rather than 20).  The expression `(hash[i] >> FILTER_SIZE)` may then give a result with 22 bits (rather than 12), which will later lead to an access to filter that is out of bounds.

Now to the explanation: The purpose of the expression

```
hash[i] = (hash[i] >> FILTER_SIZE) ^ (hash[i] & FILTER_BITMASK);
```

is to turn hash[i] into a valid bit index (plus some randomizing with the help of the ^ operation).  For ease of understanding, let's leave out the bit garbling with the ^ operator (can easily be added again).  Then, the algorithm could (more cleanly, and, hopefully, correctly for all values of FILTER_SIZE) be re-written as:

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_HASHES; ++i) {
    unsigned int bitIndex = hash[i] % (FILTER_SIZE_BYTES * 8);
    unsigned int byteIndex = bitIndex / 8;
    unsigned int bitInByte = bitIndex % 8;
    filter[byteIndex] |= (1 << bitInByte);
}
```